# Is testing existence of node module 'this' properties only meaningful for "universal" javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I recently came across this code in the beginning, top-level of a node.js module:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function(...) {...};
```

But in a node.js execution context `this === module.exports` and `module.exports` has no properties (unless assigned within the current module), so I presume this code is only meaningful when the module is executed in an context other than node.js.

I presume this because this code seems to be generated from [@angular/tsc-wrapped](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/tools/%40angular/tsc-wrapped/src/cli_options.ts.) typescript code, and the @angular compiler is executed in the browser for JIT compilation.

Is my presumption correct? Or is there a way to assign `module.exports` properties from outside the module in a node.js execution context? Perhaps configure `module.exports` to have a property for all modules?

Comment: So the real question here is "Is there a way to inject properties into all `module.exports` instances?" ?

Comment: FWIW, that code looks like it's expecting to be run at global scope, not inside a NodeJS module. I wonder if it's just not catering to NodeJS (either because it's not meant to, or because there's a bug).